# VBA macro working stopped if i open another excel sheet with copy paste cpde

Tags: excel, vba

Macro stop to work if i open another excel please help

```
Sub CopyValues()

Dim RowNo As Long
RowNo = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Sheets(2).Cells(RowNo, 4) = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 4)
    Sheets(2).Cells(RowNo, 5) = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 5)
    Sheets(2).Cells(RowNo, 6) = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6)
    Sheets(2).Cells(RowNo, 7) = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 7)
    Sheets(2).Cells(RowNo, 8) = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 8)
    Sheets(2).Cells(RowNo, 9) = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 9)
    Sheets(2).Cells(RowNo, 10) = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 10)

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:03:00"), "CopyValues"
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to qualify your Sheet references with a Workbook reference else your Sheets will refer to the active workbook and not the calling workbook.

Comment: Can you edit this code and share with me i will put my excel sheet name and update accordingly

Comment: Your request suggests some laziness on your part.  Getting an understanding on how to qualify methods in excel with Workbook/Worksheet references is not very hard.  There are many many examples on SO and elsewhere if you do even a cursory search.